# Vocabularies don't appear when Taxonomy Access Control installed?

Tags: users, nodes, taxonomy-terms

I have 3 Vocabularies called Country, Project, Research Communities. I installed [Taxonomy Access Control](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_access) module. I haven't configured it yet. But as soon as I install the module, if Anonymous or Authenticated user try to create a content, it doesn't show all the three vocabularies.
Earlier, when someone used to create a content, it used to show Country, Project, and Research Communities. User could select accordingly. But it doesn't show now.

Any idea?

**EDIT 1:** Taxonomy Access Control Configuration
[image]

Comment: It's an access control module. meaning it's intent is to control access, which sounds exactly like it's doing what it should.  If you haven't configured it yet, how can you expect it to function the way you want?

Comment: Do you mean the [Taxonomy Access Control](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_access) or [Control Acccess](https://www.drupal.org/project/content_access)? I have installed Taxonomy Access Control module and configured it.

Comment: ok, in your question you write "I haven't configured it yet" which suggested a huge gap in the process.

Comment: yeah, I had not configured it earlier. But I did later. It is still the same. As soon as I enable the module (even after configuring it), the vocabularies disappear from the "Create Content" page. After configuring the Taxonomy Control module, it shows the content according to the role of the user.
But when someone tries to create a content, They can't choose any country, the option has vanished. I hope I have explained the situation.

Comment: does it appear if the Admin tries to create new content?

Comment: yeah. If Admin tries to create a content, then everything is fine. He can choose any country, any project, any research community

Comment: Then that suggests you have a permissions problem. Double-check the configuration and global permissions to make sure the appropriate roles have access to the appropriate items.

Comment: I have installed [Field Permission](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions) module, and I have given "Public" permission to all the three vocabularies. I also checked the global permission, but there is nothing related taxonomies there. Everyone can access them. I am sure it is something to do with permissions, but I can't find what permission is overriding it.

Comment: were it me, as a test and assuming it is a permissions issue, I would create a new temporary role, and grant it ALL permissions - if a user under that role can access the vocabularies, start taking away permissions until they don't have access and you will know which permission is causing the problem.

Comment: I tested, it's `Administer vocabularies and terms` permission. If I remove this permission from a role, it doesn't show all the three vocabularies in "Create Content". But I can't give this permission of administering vocabularies and terms to anonymous users or Authenticated Users.

Comment: that permission will bypass all access controls. I would suggest that Taxonomy Access Control is not configured properly.

Comment: I have added the screenshot of configuration for anonymous, authenticated and testing(STFC) role. Please have a look.

Comment: what happens if you set Update to A (allow)?

Comment: if you haven't already, try going through the TAC trouble shooting guide (https://www.drupal.org/node/731850)

Comment: If I set update to A (allow), then they can edit the content, which I don't want them to do. I only want user with STFC role to edit the content which has STFC as Project. So I have set Update A and Delete A only for STFC Role --> Project STFC. And I have I will go through this guide.